# how to show my ads only for 10 second in android app

Tags: android, timer, admob, ads, interstitial

I'm using a Interstitial Ad By Ad Mob,
I want to set timer for 5 seconds on the top of the Ad,
After 5 second, A massage display "Skip Ad Now" 
Any help will be use full for me.

Comment: When your Ad is Loaded, start a CountDown for 5 seconds, then on the onFinish() callback, show 'Skip Ad Now'

Comment: @DarShan how can i perform this any link or code please